# Vuejs2 - emitting synthetic event to window object without tying the listener to Vue instance

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Is is possible to emit a [synthetic event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) from a watched property in a way, that will not be checking the listeners (outside of Vue instance) on Vue instance initialization?

I have a situation in which I would like to watch for that synthetic event on a window object and perform a certain action on an object which does not exist at the time the Vue instance is created.

No matter how I try it to go about it I am getting an error:

```
Cannot read property 'set' of undefined
```

In my particular case, I want to 'move' the slider handle (I am using [noUiSlider](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/) library) to a new position whenever the watched property changes - that is, the error message is specific, but my question refers to the generic case - is it possible? And if yes, how to do it?

Comment: When/how is the object created?

Comment: I think you just need the listener to be set up in the code where the slider is created.

Comment: @RoyJ Thanks! It worked :) If you post it as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @BertEvans I am creating it on document.ready() event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the listener to be able to operate on the slider, create the listener when you create the slider. There's no point to creating it before the slider exists.